# How do I convert type _ComObject to a native type like Long or other (getting cast error)?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to get the `LastLogonTimestamp` from Active Directory by calling

```
Principal.ExtensionGet("lastLogonTimestamp")
```

VB.NET code:

```vb
<DirectoryProperty("lastLogonTimestamp")>
Public Property LastLogonTimestamp() As Date? ' no matter what this type is, I cannot cast the Object coming in
    Get
        Dim valueArray = ExtensionGet("lastLogonTimestamp")
        If valueArray Is Nothing OrElse valueArray.Length = 0 Then Return Nothing
        Return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(valueArray(0))
    End Get
    Set(value As Date?)
        ExtensionSet("lastLogonTimestamp", value)
    End Set
End Property
```

This returns an array of `Object` (i.e. `Object()`) or `null`.  The trouble is it complains about my cast to `Long` (or other types I have tried like: `ULong`, `Date`, and `String`). It always tells me something like this:

> Conversion from type '_ComObject' to type 'Long' is not valid.

In [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063943/how-to-convert-datetime-to-64-bit-representation), I set out to go the other way (from DateTime to 64 bit)

Comment: What do you see in the debugger if you stop the code on the `If()` line and evaluate `valueArray(0).ToString()`?

Comment: If `valueArray(0)` is truly a `Long` then you may need to either use `CLng(valueArray(0))` or `DirectCast(valueArray(0), Long)`

Comment: Also... there's no need for including notes like "updated" or "original question". Stack Overflow preserves the entire edit history for anyone to see, and so those notes only tend to slow us down when trying to help you.

Comment: I believe this will return a [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx) and not a Date value.  Or test using `String` and `...utc.toString`

Comment: @JimmySmith In Vb.net, DateTime and Date are the same thing. Date aliases to DateTime.

Comment: It is an IAdsLargeInteger.  You have to glue the date together from the HighPart and LowPart, example is visible on [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active).  Backgrounder [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987996/how-does-invokemember-know-about-the-highpart-property).

Comment: @HansPassant this looks useful.  Working on it... (thanks)

Comment: Make sure you post back what worked as an answer. :)

Comment: @HansPassant getting 'arithmetic overflow' on assignment of long (see my UPDATE above).  Am I doing that right?  I am going to pick this up tomorrow morning.  Thanks!

Comment: UInt32 is not correct, 50% odds for the LowPart to be negative  You were lucky.  Consider CLng(hi) << 32 Or (CLng(lo) And &HFFFFFFFFL)

Comment: @HansPassant thanks you sir!   And you know what... I have code in this project that does exactly this work, and it was gnawing at me to go take a look.  Instead I posted here, and you hit the nail on the head.  Kudos!

Comment: @HansPassant trying to go the other way now in this new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063943/how-to-convert-datetime-to-64-bit-representation

Comment: Sounds like you got it working. Why don't you reply to your own question with the working code, so it can be marked as the correct answer? Leaving good artifacts for future searches is an important part of Stack Overflow. Adding a "SOLUTION" section to the question is **NOT** what we want to see.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the advice.  Done!

Answer (score 3):

Using C# code provided in [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active) via HansPassant's comment below, I resolved this with the following VB code:

```
<DirectoryProperty("lastLogonTimestamp")>
Public Property LastLogonTimestamp() As Date?
    Get
        'Dim valueArray = GetProperty("whenChanged")
        Dim valueArray = ExtensionGet("lastLogonTimestamp") 'ExtensionGet("LastLogon")
        If valueArray Is Nothing OrElse valueArray.Length = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Dim lastLogonDate = valueArray(0)
        Dim lastLogonDateType = lastLogonDate.GetType()
        Dim highPart = CType(lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("HighPart", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, lastLogonDate, Nothing), Int32)
        Dim lowPart = CType(lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("LowPart", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, Nothing, lastLogonDate, Nothing), Int32)
        Dim longDate = CLng(highPart) << 32 Or (CLng(lowPart) And &HFFFFFFFFL)
        Dim result = IIf(longDate > 0, CType(DateTime.FromFileTime(longDate), DateTime?), Nothing)

        Return result
        'Return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(valueArray(0))
    End Get
    Set(value As Date?)
        ExtensionSet("lastLogonTimestamp", value)
    End Set
End Property
```

And the C# version (clipped from [source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active)):

```
[DirectoryProperty("RealLastLogon")]
public DateTime? RealLastLogon
{
    get
    {
        if (ExtensionGet("LastLogon").Length > 0)
        {
            var lastLogonDate = ExtensionGet("LastLogon")[0];
            var lastLogonDateType = lastLogonDate.GetType();
            var highPart = (Int32)lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, lastLogonDate, null);
            var lowPart = (Int32)lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, lastLogonDate, null);

            var longDate = ((Int64)highPart << 32 | (UInt32)lowPart);

            return longDate > 0 ? (DateTime?) DateTime.FromFileTime(longDate) : null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```