# How to convert DateTime to 64 bit representation?

Tags: vb.net

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059032/how-do-i-convert-type-comobject-to-a-native-type-like-long-or-other-getting-ca), I asked how to convert 64 bit _ComObject to native DateTime.  I would like to also be able to do the reverse.

The code to convert 64 bit _ComObject to DateTime:

```
<DirectoryProperty("lastLogonTimestamp")>
Public Property LastLogonTimestamp() As Date?
    Get
        'Dim valueArray = GetProperty("whenChanged")
        Dim valueArray = ExtensionGet("lastLogonTimestamp") 'ExtensionGet("LastLogon")
        If valueArray Is Nothing OrElse valueArray.Length = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Dim lastLogonDate = valueArray(0)
        Dim lastLogonDateType = lastLogonDate.GetType()
        Dim highPart = CType(lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("HighPart", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, lastLogonDate, Nothing), Int32)
        Dim lowPart = CType(lastLogonDateType.InvokeMember("LowPart", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, Nothing, lastLogonDate, Nothing), Int32)
        Dim longDate = CLng(highPart) << 32 Or CLng(lowPart)
        Dim result = IIf(longDate > 0, CType(DateTime.FromFileTime(longDate), DateTime?), Nothing)

        Return result
        'Return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(valueArray(0))
    End Get
    Set(value As Date?)
        ExtensionSet("lastLogonTimestamp", value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Working with an example DateTime value of #2/19/2018 8:17:20 AM#, I need a conversion to come back with 64 bit representing both date and time parts.  I believe that value should be 131635198405088370, and the reason I think so is because AD says so when I inspect the datetime value.

I have tried this..

```
Dim my64bitDate = DateTime.Parse("#2/19/2018 8:17:20 AM#").ToFileTime
```

... which returns 131635198400000000, which is only part of the value I expect.

UPDATE:

Based on HansPrassant's input, I tried more precise datetime value of 2/19/2018 8:17:21 0000001 AM (adding 1 second and 1 nanosecond?), and this resulted in value 131635198410000001 so I believe this is working and correct.

Comment: What is "64 but"? Avoid typos please.

Comment: No, the unit of ToFileTime is 100 nanoseconds.  But you specified a time accurate only to 1 second, the best you can do with a vb.net literal.  So that inevitably must always produce 7 zeros at the end.  The value you got back from AD is just more precise than 1 second, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @HansPassant are you saying that the value of 131635198400000000 is inclusive of the time part ?  And that the last 8 zeros are for purposes of a precision beyond the second part of the time ?  (I just checked this by adding 1 to the seconds and saw it come in as a 1 in my value.  Seems good)  THanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works... `Dim my64bitDate = DateTime.Parse("#2/19/2018 8:17:20 AM#").ToFileTime`

Originally, I had been using a value from Active Directory property  `lastLogonTimestamp` that contained more precise value.  This precision is not required to use as a filter on the property.  A good thing because it is lost during the above parse.

If the original question, and comments don't clear things up, ask a question in the comments below - and I will do my best to answer.  Thanks.